# SAS Enterprise Miner Server Directory

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, enterprise-miner

I am new to SAS enterprise Miner and trying to create my first project.

When I click on "New Project", I was prompted to enter "project name" and "server directory".

When I entered a project-name and local-directory (C:\Folder-name) I am getting following error message.

"This server location is already registered for use..."

Can someone help me what directory should I specify in "Server-directory"?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding [tag:enterprise-guide] as that is similar enough the same problem may crop up there.

Comment: You need to talk to your administrator, it depends on your set up.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to correct the behavior.

1. Go to C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASEnterpriseMinerWorkstationConfiguration
2. Right-Click SASEnterpriseMinerWorkstationConfiguration.
3. Select the **Security** tab.
4. Give "**Write**" access to all SAS Enterprise Miner Users.